# Is it possible to remove the "cancel" button in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UIImagePickerController as one view in a TabBar setup.  Is it possible to tell the UIImagePickerController to not show the Cancel button in the top navigation bar when browsing photos libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a supported way. UIImagePickerController is designed to be shown as a modal controller.

Comment: Ah ha! That now makes it all crystal clear.  Thanks millenomi for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a short blog article on customizing the view hierarchy created by UIImagePickerController. It's targetted at the camera capture mode rather than photo library, but the principles should be the same.

See: [The Airsource - Views of UIImagePickerController](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2008/11/11/views-of-uiimagepickercontroller/)